# Core 2.0 MVC taghelper generating links without href

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm new to the Core 2.0 framework (not to MVC though) and am expanding the ContosoUniversity demo project to include some wanted functionality to see if this is the way to go for an upcoming application I intend to build. One of these things is Areas.

Instead of having the demo "Students" controller, models and views in their default folders, I've created an area "Education" and placed the StudentsController in its Controllers folder, the models in the Models folder, then used Scaffolding to create the views there:
[Areas folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnKRh.png)

The Configure method in Startup.cs was modified to setup area routing:

```
// Map static routes
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Map MVC routing
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // Area routes
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            // Default MVC routing
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

When testing the application, it loads fine and I can consult the /Education/Students page as expected. However, when verifying the CRUD links generated by the framework, they do not seem to have an HREF property and as such don't work. When I change it to an ActionLink it does work however:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit 1", "Edit", "Students", new { area = "Education", id = item.ID }, null) // works
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-area="Education" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit 1</a> // does not work
```

The link generated by the actionlink is http://localhost:61541/Education/Students/Edit?id=1.

However, to get this to work I had to modify the controller to include routing decorators, which, from the examples, should not have been necessary if I understood the tutorial correctly because the current Area should be  stickied into links. There may be an underlying issue related to that but I can't figure it out somehow. Controller, index action and edit action:

```
    namespace ContosoUniversity.Areas.Education
{
    [Area("Education")]
    [Route("Education/[controller]")]
    public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EducationContext _context;

        public StudentsController(EducationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Education/Students        
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Students.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Education/Students/Edit/5
        [Route("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Students.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

So my questions:

1. How can I get the taghelpers to generate proper links, and
2. Did I fudge something up somewhere with the ActionLinks needing all kinds
   of routing to work at all?

Edit: naviating to the Edit URL with the actionlink results in an empty form. The model is correctly filled in the controller and it returns the proper view, but without filling the fields using the generated code:

```
<input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
```

If I however add @Model.LastName to the HTML I DO see the correct name rendered. What am I missing? Somehow the model not binding correctly? :(

Comment: in the tag helper, have you tried adding: asp-controller="nameofcontroller"? As for why the edit page do not show the lastname text, if you only pass the student class to the view, how can the input fielt automatically know how to populate a text property within that class? either by referencing the field directly as you did with Model.LastName or create a proper viewmodel with explicit properties for each input

Comment: Adding `asp-controller="Students"` does not resolve the problem unfortunately, still the href remains empty.
As for the input field, aha I figured the `<input asp-for="LastName">` directive was similar to `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)` where its value is automatically set. Specifying it works. Not sure what you mean though with proper viewmodel as I am using one with explicit properties for each input :)